# Multiple file export from excel xml schema

Tags: excel, xml

I'm looking for a way to export table from excel to xml but every excel line should be different xml file, not as a default one xml file with all data.
So for example table like the one below:

[image]

This table should be exported into 3 xml files
first file 1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <TAGNAME1>mark</TAGNAME1>
        <TAGNAME2>tom</TAGNAME2>
        <TAGNAME3>london</TAGNAME3>
    </record>
    </student-data>
```

second file 2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<student-data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
        <TAGNAME1>julie</TAGNAME1>
        <TAGNAME2>jan</TAGNAME2>
        <TAGNAME3>manchester</TAGNAME3>
    </record>
    </student-data>
```

etc...

Any ideas how to do that?

I've tried to use developer mode in excel with xml tab, but it export one file with all data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using an XLSX file, you'll find it's actually a zip file. In its `xl/worksheets`  subdirectory, the `sheet1.xml` and similarly named files (`sheet2.xml`, `sheet3.xml`, ...) represent the tabs that you see in the Excel file.

Typically, `sheet1.xml` will contain something like:

```xml
<worksheet...>
  ...
  <sheetData>
    <row r="1">
      <c r="A1">...</c>
      <c r="B1">...</c>
    </row>
    <row r="2">
      <c r="A2">...</c>
      <c r="B2">...</c>
    </row>
  </sheetData>
</worksheet>
```

Comparing that XML to what you see in Excel, you'll quickly spot the way a worksheet is encoded in XML. The `<row><c/></row>` structures almost immediately translate to what you need.

Strings are typically handled in a special way.
A cell with string contents usually contains a ***reference*** to a string value specified elsewhere. In the `<c>` element, the attribute `t="s"` indicates a referenced string. *(the `s` attribute references a style id)*. The `<v>` element contains the string reference.

The zero-indexed reference list is stored in the `xl/sharedStrings.xml` file. Multiple occurrences of the same string will be stored more efficiently this way *(instead of keeping them inline in the cells, which could result in multiple duplicates of the same string)*.

Using `xmlstarlet` and/or XSLT combined with some BaSH scripting for loops and handling file input and output, you could then get your desired result.

This is not an instant answer to what you want, but instead a nudge in the direction you could go. Your choice of tooling may vary. You'll learn useful things along the way. Learning curves may be steep but rewarding eventually. In the end, this will probably teach you more than any precooked answer.